# Displaying a random string on a TextView in a layout

Tags: android, arrays, string, random, textview

Hey all - In Android, I wrote a number of strings in my string.xml I would like to display on a TextView based on a random number...Here is what I have:

```
  int randCropPercentage = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);  
  Random randPhrase50 = new Random();
        int[] array50 = new int[] { R.string.ss2, R.string.ss4, R.string.ss5,
                R.string.st4, R.string.st5, R.string.tt2, R.string.tt3,
                R.string.tt5, R.string.to2, R.string.to3, R.string.to4,
                R.string.os5 };
        int randPhrase = randPhrase50.nextInt(array50.length - 1);
```

Inside an if statement, I have this:

```
 if (randomCropPercentage < 50){
                mTheMessage.setText(array50(randPhrase));
                            //etc
```

But I know I am not doing it right because I get the error:

```
The method array50(int) is undefined for the type MAIN
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is you should write this:

```
array50[randPhrase]
```

Arrays give the access to elements not via `()`, but via `[]`

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array is with `[]`

Try this :
`mTheMessage.setText(array50[randPhrase]);`